# How does the browser distinguish between escaped strings and actual HTML when both are displayed similarly?

Tags: html, xss

If I place `<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">` inside the `body` tag, and if I place the following string inside the body tag "`&lt;a href=&quot;www.stackoverflow.com&quot;&gt;`", how does the browser know that the first is to be rendered as an actual link, and the latter as simple text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The less than character “<” is defined to be a tag start character. The notation `&lt;` is something completely different; it simply means the less than character as a data character, not interpreted as markup at all. So the answer is really “By definition.”

By the way, `href="www.stackoverflow.com"` contains a relative address, resolved relative to the current base address. To refer to StackOverflow main page, you need to write `href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"`.

Answer (score 1):

If we uses **reserved characters/ HTML tags** in our html pages they are rendered as markups by the borwsers.Some times we are in need to use these  charcatres  as itself not as markups then we have to use some escape sequences to achive them.

you can get a good idea of **how browsers work** from [this](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm) link.

you can find some escape sequences from [here](http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256C47007456E7)
In our case  `<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">`  in that  `<` and `>` are  a reserved charcter by html when ever it uses in the page its rendered as an html tag 
but if you want to use or display `<` or `>` in your page you have to use coresponding escape sequence. thats how browsers replaces the `&lt;` as `<` and displayed in the page